# Suggestions for MySQL table design schema

Tags: mysql

I started with a **media** table to store basic information (id, path, filename, mime, filesize, md5, etc.. ) for a directory tree of say 1 million images and 1,000 movies.  I need to add a few new columns (title, description, runtime) pertaining mostly to the movies, and will need to query on title matches.  With 1+ million rows that will not have a title, I don't think I should add the additional columns to 'media' because it'll give me 1+ million empty/null rows where it doesn't apply.  I have a **media_meta** (id, media_id, meta_key, meta_value) table that stores a serialized value of miscellaneous information, title is one of them but now I need to be able to index just the 'title' for searching.  Should I add another table **media_titles** with just media_id, title with an index on title, for a query like:

`SELECT * FROM media_titles WHERE title LIKE '%title%';`

I realize the above query isn't optimal yet, but still it's something I'll need to do, ie. searching for a substring in the titles.

TABLES summary:

```
media (id, path, filename, filesize, mime, md5, etc...)
media_meta (id, media_id, meta_key, meta_value)
media_titles (media_id, title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Table design is practically irrelevant if you lead with a wildcard on your title search as you have done in your sample query. Without some sort of full text search feature, that is - of which I am not too familiar.

MySQL (or any RDBMS) cannot make use of the index on a column when you lead with a wildcard, as far as i know.

Comment: Yes, I had thought of that after posting and went looking for alternative solutions to query on title for a substring.  It's necessary, but not sure how I'll solve it yet.

Comment: Will this feature work? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html